# Custom Data Input to RTAB instead of Kinect data

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python script which after processing, gives me **Depth Map** and **RGB Input image** in realtime. I can not connect kinect directly, but I want RTAB Map to create a map based on the live stream of Depth map and RGB Images processed by **Python**. How can I do that? I have reasonable experience in Python, but I'm a rookie in ROS.
Does the RTABMap access data via topic/subscribing to some topic? I have little clue, please help me on this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328577/custom-data-input-to-rtab-instead-of-kinect-data/) by [Karan Shah](https://answers.ros.org/users/44062/karan-shah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rtabmap_ros](http://rgb_topic:=%22my/python/rgb/image/topic%22) uses topics as input. Topics you need are a RGB image, a registered depth image and camera info of RGB image. See http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping for many examples using different cameras. You should be able to do the same with your python script, just make sure you republish the images in different topic names and adjust `rgb_topic`, `depth_topic` and `camera_info_topic` arguments of [rtabmap.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/2ab15ec3b9e5268e5e88d3817c5f50d2a66c9153/launch/rtabmap.launch#L56-L58):

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" rgb_topic:="my/python/rgb/image/topic" depth_topic:="my/python/depth/image/topic" camera_info_topic:="my/python/rgb/camera_info/topic"
```

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0